# Java public private key decryption issue

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a message as mentioned in the below code. Basically I want to encrypt a message with a public key and convert that encrypted message from byte array to String. And decrypt this string into original text. Here are the both methods. Here encryption works fine but decryption fails (error is "Data must start with zero"). I think this is causing because I convert encrypted byte array into String. 
 
How do I solve this? (I want to have encrypted byte array as string and use it for decryption) Is there any other approach (with public and private keys)

```
public static String getEncryptedMessage(String publicKeyFilePath,

    String plainMessage) {
    byte[] encryptedBytes;
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        byte[] publicKeyContentsAsByteArray = getBytesFromFile(publicKeyFilePath);
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(publicKeyContentsAsByteArray);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainMessage.getBytes());
        return new String(encryptedBytes);
    } catch (Throwable t) {

    }

}
public static String getDecryptedMessage(
        String privateKeyFilePath, String encryptedMessage)
         {
    byte[] decryptedMessage;
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        byte[] privateKeyContentsAsByteArray = getBytesFromFile(privateKeyFilePath);
        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(privateKeyContentsAsByteArray);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage.getBytes());
        return new String(decryptedMessage);
    } catch (Throwable t) {


}
```

Comment: You should not convert the encrypted byte array directly to a String. If you need it in a printable form convert it Base64. You can use the Base64 encoder from Apache commons codec: [link(]http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this page (http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/Secret_Key_Cryptography_Tutorial) you will need to do base-64 encoding to turn the bytes into a string, then to decrypt it you would just decode it then decrypt.

Base-64 encoding uses the first 7 bits of a byte, to make something that is printable or emailable, for example.

**UPDATE:**

I made a mistake, there are 64 characters that it would be encoded in, again, in order to make it easier to use as something printable.

Comment: Downvoted because this is misleading/correct.  If the OP were willing to work with byte arrays, base64 encoding is not necessary.  And also, "uses the first 7 bits of a byte" is not at all how base64 works.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples

Comment: @Jumbogram - OK, 64 characters, I will correct that, but I expect the test is to go from encrypt to string (for saving to a file) then decrypt that.  Base-64 is the best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you treat the message as byte array from encryption to decryption? Why changing it to String in the middle? (I know it seems like a question, but it's actually an answer...)

Comment: The encryption will make more than half of the bytes (in average) unreadble or even with no matching ascii symbol, the decrypted message should be readable just like the original message, so it should be converted to string again with no problems. 
Also, since the calls to decrypt and encrypt are done with byte[] I see no reason to convert it twice again in the middle.

Comment: I want to correct my previous comment. There might be plenty of reasons to convert it to String in the middle, but in general, I think it should be avoided.

Comment: If you want to encrypt, then send an email, are you going to do it as an attachment?  If you want to include the message as part of an xml file bytes can be a difficulty.  It is generally easier to convert to a string, get it where it needs to be, then just go back to bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Using RSA directly on unformatted data may leave your application vulnerable to an *adaptive chosen ciphertext attack*. For details please see Chapter 8, pages 288-289, of the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), a freely-available book from CRC Press. (It's well worth [buying the bound edition](http://www.powells.com/biblio/63-9780849385230-0), if you're really interested in cryptography -- you'll be stunned at the quality for the price.)

Because of this attack, most protocols that integrate RSA use RSA for encrypting randomly-generated session keys or signing hash functions with outputs that ought to be indistinguishable from random, OR using very carefully formatted messages that will fail to be correctly interpreted. (See *Note 8.63* in HAC for details.)